# Can't connect directly to Pod on M1 Mac with Minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I'm building a service on Kubernetes that involves directly connecting to pods. Each pod is stateful and it's important that I'm able to connect to a specific pod in the cluster. For this reason a load balancer wont work. Also, the pod's address and port are dynamically allocated and by making a request to kubernetes api I can retrieve the address I want.

I know that Dockerd on Mac does not allow for directly connecting to pods without using a service or Nodeport. Is there any way around this? Using a different container runtime broke other workflows I had.

Comment: Can you run the client service inside the cluster too?  Inside the cluster, each replica has a [well-known DNS name](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id).  (When you go to run this workload in production, without Minikube, where do you expect the client to run?)

Comment: @DavidMaze This cluster will have Agones installed. So each pod will be a game server that can be directly connected to. Pods are "allocated" by creating an allocation CRD via a kubernetes api request and this returns a pod IP that can be connected directly to.